# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 () PHP Website

Tags: php

When i try to open my PHP website, it's giving the 500 error in the console. The error log shows this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '../assets/init.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/share/pear') in /home3/bcaftanc/public_html/thequrantube/index.php on line 13
```

But in the index.php file in line 13, i don't have it like the error says, it's written like this:

```
require_once('./assets/init.php');
```

What could be the issue ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Fatal Error Failed opening required File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364233/php-fatal-error-failed-opening-required-file)

Comment: @Skully not really, still have the same issue

Comment: Can you confirm that the file exists in the path you're using, and that PHP has the according permissions required to access it?

Comment: @Skully yes the path is correct, and php has permissions to access it!